# Getting "can only post questions every 20 minutes" but did not post recently

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions, new-users, rate-limiting

Trying to post a question (on StackOverflow), and get the message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes; try again later.

I have not posted any questions within the last 20 minutes. Specifically I haven't posted a question since "nov 24 at 1:21" in 2009.

Comment: This might be one of many bugs related to the new "draft" feature

Comment: On something like the 5th try, I was able to submit the question. Is it possible that the criteria is comments, answers, and questions combined?

Comment: Did you get this error on your first attempt to submit, or did you try to submit but got a different error, then corrected and retried and got this error?

Comment: The error was on my first and subsequent attempts to submit until the final submit, when it successfully posted.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Haven't used my account in over a year, just created a question and keep getting this message. Nobody else in my company would use Stackoverlow so can't be an issue with IP address as suggested below. Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have to throttle user activity based on IP address and your IP has collisions with several other accounts.

When you tried posting your question, another user on your same IP had also posted a new question - this is why the throttle was enforced.

We're sorry about this mechanism, but there's not much we can do to alleviate it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It was pretty confusing behavior for me.

Comment: Curious: does this only take questions from users < 125 into account? (So, in the answer above, was "another user" actually "another < 125 user"?)

Comment: We are over 35 thousand users sitting behind a big natting firewall. My co-worker tried to post a new question and got that throttling error message. He was logged in with his own account. Is there no way to throttle on the accounts instead of IP addresses?

Comment: @delixfe it's a bit too easy to create new accounts for the throttle to really work. Only for relatively higer-rep users this could possibly work.