# Not allowed to ask a question even though I have not posted anything

Tags: support, help

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Can't Post Question - Status Incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66844/cant-post-question-status-incorrect)

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20
> minutes; try again later.

This message is displayed when I ask a question even though I have not asked any question or posted anything today. What to do?

Comment: looks like you had [one deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471375/spreadsheet-format-options-in-ruby) 2 days ago, may be bug related to that?

Comment: so what could be the possible solution to post..

Comment: @GhostRider, wait for the dev team to response.

Comment: @Arjan, your answer is valid answer imho.

Comment: Yes, @YOU, but I think it's a duplicate, so no need to repeat the (now deleted) answer then?

Comment: @Arjan, Imm, I see, I still don't get that theory though, yesterday I read [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) about dups through Will's post, thought dups were not that bad.

Comment: Okay, I will delete again when/if this gets closed as a duplicate then, @you. ;-) (In the end, a simple search on the error message showed the duplicate; not the kind of duplicates that are helpful to people who use the search, and will get one definitive answer by a SE team member, and my answer that refers to that. I think...)

Comment: (Confused about the handling of duplicates now, @YOU. Should one answer *and* vote to close...? I thought today's Unicorns were the only new thing for me!)

Comment: @Arjan, I am not sure that too, looks ok to me, but there may be someone discouraging that. but anyway, at least I learnt the existance of such mechanism from your answer.

Answer (score 5):

This [is based on IP address](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66844/cant-post-question-status-incorrect/66859#66859), so most likely there are other accounts using the same IP address?

Comment: Ah, that could be the case

Comment: Yes, @YOU, and failing a response from the OP, I guess this is just a duplicate then...

Comment: Yep, probably other people in his company have accounts here as well and he's not aware of that.