# Trying to ask a question on StackOverflow, but am being blocked

Tags: support, questions, rate-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't Post Question - Status Incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66844/cant-post-question-status-incorrect)

I haven't posted any other questions today on StackOverflow, yet when I try, I keep getting the following error:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be
>   submitted because:
>
> Users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions
>   every 20 minutes; try again later.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shared IP probably

Comment: I assume you got an upvote on a question since asking this? Or did you have 129 rep when this was posted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're sharing an IP with another user, who asked a question 18 minutes ago.

Our throttling in these low rep cases is IP based, as otherwise they would be trivially circumventable.