# Getting "you are only allowed to ask 6 questions in a 24 hour period" for my first question ever

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

I have just created an account with Stack Overflow. I was trying to post my first question  regarding 'svnsync' and was disappointed to see the below error:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> • Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 6 questions in a 24 hour period

Comment: I believe it remembers your IP and cookies :D. So "somebody" asked 6 question from your IP, or your computer before

Comment: Related: [Getting “can only post questions every 20 minutes” but did not post recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66844/getting-can-only-post-questions-every-20-minutes-but-did-not-post-recently).

Answer (score 10):

This filter also works on the IP level. It is possible that you share a public IP with many other computers, and that other users used these computers to ask other questions.

This is unfortunate, but there is no other good way to make that limit effective.