# Why am I hitting a question rate limit when I haven't posted all day?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, rate-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Getting “can only post questions every 20 minutes” but did not post recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66844/getting-can-only-post-questions-every-20-minutes-but-did-not-post-recently)

I only have 107 reputation on Stack Overflow. Often when I try posting a question I get this error, even though it's my first question of the day (meaning I haven't posted a question for over 12 hours):

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes; try again later.

Why is this happening? Is it possible that a failed captcha check could cause it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's another user who shares your IP address, also has a very low reputation on the site, and asked a question just a few minutes before you tried to post yours.

So, you got blocked.

Once 20 minutes passed from the time this other user posted, you were able to post.

Comment: In my company all the users are using a same proxy thats why i got blocked. So there is no way except i got 125 reputation

Comment: Yup. Or, I suppose, coordinate with your co-workers. But really, you're almost there already.

Comment: yes, but the developers of stckoverflow can taken into account that there are large number of persons especially in the colleges who are provided a single proxy address. In this case if a college has almost 2000 users in that case its like a race condition whose question will get posted. This should be taken into account. We expect this form stackoverflow.

Comment: The rate-limiting is in effect to prevent [a very serious problem](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/) - don't expect to see it changed any time soon. If you're asking a large number of questions, you should go out of your way to ensure they are high-quality and get up-voted - this is a good idea *anyway*, but in this case also helps you get past the "new user restrictions" faster.