# Getting "can only post questions every 20 minutes" but posted over 10 hours ago

Tags: support, asking-questions, new-users, time-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Getting “can only post questions every 20 minutes” but did not post recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66844/getting-can-only-post-questions-every-20-minutes-but-did-not-post-recently)

I did not post a question for more than 10 hours, but still I get following error:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes; try again later

Comment: Does [Getting “can only post questions every 20 minutes” but did not post recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66844/getting-can-only-post-questions-every-20-minutes-but-did-not-post-recently) answer this for you?

Comment: (Voting to close anyway, since you did not indicate in your question that you already read that, and it was quite easy to find given the error message. If things are different, we can reopen again.)

Comment: @Arjan yep that's about the only explanation so it's a duplicate.