# A question about the limit on the number of questions that can be asked

Tags: discussion

This may seem to be similar to other questions asked on this site, but I feel the answers given there do not answer my query. Hence this question.

For 3-4 days now, I have been unable to ask questions on http://math.stackexchange.com. Apparently, it is because I have asked more than 50 questions in a period of 30 days, which I don't believe to be true.

How can I work around this? I self-study mathematics, and this has destroyed my flow. StackExchange has been the best thing about my life for some time now, and I don't know what to do now that it is beyond reach.

Comment: [This question covers the staff's justification for why this limit exists.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217/152515).

Comment: When I was learning to code certain languages, I used SO for **EVERYTHING**. I was going nuts, asking questions left, right and centre about every niggling little issue I faced. I never hit 50 questions per month.

Comment: @danielhanly.com- I too have not hit the 50 question limit, and I've been a member of the site for 5 months now. And the number of questions I asked last month was much lower than before. I don't understand why this happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual limit you hit is 50 questions per month. This is a pretty reasonable limit in my opinion, and if you are hitting it is usually means that you aren't trying hard enough to solve your questions yourself before asking them.

If I read your history correctly, I think you should be able to continue asking questions in 2-3 days. You should try to reduce the number of questions you ask by trying to avoid easy questions you could have answered yourself.

You questions seem to be generally well-received, I don't see any closed or downvoted questions so you seem to understand the rules of the site.

I'll also caution you against trying to circumvent the limit in any way, this will result in a suspension of your account.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is Details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask)

- [50 questions over any 30-day period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)
- [six questions over any 24-hour period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/increase-the-limit-of-6-questions-in-24-hours)
- one question over any 30-second period
- [users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66844)

Comment: The question's asking about how to work around it, not asking for the limits themselves. :)